# Running an ANOVA (repeated measures two-way ANOVA) with unequal sample sizes

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, two-way

We have four sites, within each site we tagged 40 mangrove individuals and measured their height every 3 months for 2 years. We have three mangrove species present within each site but it is mainly dominated by one species, we tried tagging and measuring a mix of species but we ended up with 118 tagged individuals of species A, 22 of species B, and 20 of species C.

Can I run a repeated measures anova with site and species as a factor to determine if it significantly affects the height? Or is there an issue from not having equal number of samples for each species. I would like to compare height between species, but would a different model be more appropriate?